# App crashes on implementing Scrolled Card Views

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-cardview, android-scrollview

Below is my Code. The code is in the format

```
 <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
         <CardView>  <LinearLayout> <TextView> <ImageView> </LinearLayout> </CardView>
         .  //5 more card views similar to this of same Content.
         .
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The apps crashes when it runs on the Phone. The logcat reads

```
01-08 12:12:46.869 24638-24740/com.example.android.cardapplication 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-08 12:12:49.082 24638-24740/com.example.android.cardapplication I/Adreno: BLTLIB: Semaphore error, disabling MT
01-08 12:12:51.089 24638-24740/com.example.android.cardapplication I/Adreno: BLTLIB: Semaphore error count 1
01-08 12:13:03.269 24638-24638/com.example.android.cardapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 346 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-08 12:13:08.353 24638-24643/com.example.android.cardapplication I/art: Thread[2,tid=24643,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x55c739e330,peer=0x12d5a0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
01-08 12:13:08.419 24638-24643/com.example.android.cardapplication I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-08 12:13:11.863 24638-24638/com.example.android.cardapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 515 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-08 12:13:14.860 24638-24638/com.example.android.cardapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 179 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-08 12:13:24.432 24638-24638/com.example.android.cardapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 214 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-08 12:13:28.753 24638-24638/com.example.android.cardapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 258 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I have also added the CardView dependencies, 
have tried with nested Scroll view and
have used Layout_height="wrap_content" in the cardView but to no avail. 
I had not added anything in MainActivity.Java too.

Please specify my error and alternate ways which I had to follow.

My Full code is given below:-

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FILTER COFFEE"
            android:textColor="#ffff00" />

      </LinearLayout>

     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     android:id="@+id/cardview5"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="182dp"
     android:layout_margin="5dp"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FILTER COFFEE"
             android:textColor="#ffff00" />

     </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FILTER COFFEE"
            android:textColor="#ffff00" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FILTER COFFEE"
            android:textColor="#ffff00" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FILTER COFFEE"
            android:textColor="#ffff00" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FILTER COFFEE"
            android:textColor="#ffff00" />

       </LinearLayout>

     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What should I do to resolve my error?

Comment: add your activity code and whole log cat error msg

Comment: Post your complete logs

Comment: Maybe your layout is too complex to be rendered via hardware acceleration. Try to run your activity with android:hardwareAccelerated="false" under your manifest